# Facebook pixel Purchase event deduplication

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel, conversion-tracking

How can one avoid a duplicate `Purchase` event when doing conversion tracking with a Facebook pixel? I'm wondering if I can send a unique ID with the event somehow to avoid tracking that event more than once (if, for instance, the user reloads the "thank you"/"confirmation" of purchase page.

I thought about saving a "has_tracked_purchase" field along with the transaction data and only loading the pixel if that is `false` and setting it to `true` once the pixel is tracked.

I'm surprised to not find a way to handle deduplication with the Facebook Pixel API.

Answer (score 1):

An init flag might remove the duplicate pixel error all over the place.
If you are using shopify platform then you can use:

`{% if first_time_accessed %}`

It will fire purchase only one time.

Comment: helpful, but not using shopify

Comment: Which platform you are using ?